# Select legend items in ArcMap

Tags: raster, arcmap, legend, classification

I have classified class interval with pixel value (i.e. >1 & < 0 ) as Non-Bamboo area after excluding these values in image classification. However, these classes appear in 2 rows in legends of the map as shown.

[image]

Is there any idea to select legend items of the legend so that I can remove of the legend item named Non-Bamboo.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the layer in your table of contents.  Open the symbology for that layer.  Click (highlight) non-bamboo to select the classification you want to remove.  Right click and choose Remove Classes from the resulting dialog box.  Non-bamboo will be removed from the symbology and also from the legend.

Comment: This method works for a polygon, but will not work if it is a raster layer. Right click the desired classification in the Symbology tab and select Remove Classes.

Comment: Correct.  I have edited my answer.